# Using WSL g++ Compiler From Visual Studio Code (Windows 10)

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've really been struggling for a long time to get VS Code to work properly so I'm finally deciding to post my question here. I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 to write C++ code. For the class I'm taking I have to be able to run my code on a Linux machine. I have been using the remote WSL mode within VS Code but it is driving me crazy for two reasons.

1. The enhanced syntax colorization doesn't work from the remote mode.
2. I need to turn my files in for a class and I can't access the Linux files from Windows 10 explorer.

So the ideal situation would be to use the regular (not remote) version of Visual Studio Code but still compile and debug with Linux. The Visual Code Documentation (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) makes it appear as though this is possible but I have no idea what the compiler path is for WSL g++. Any suggestions?

Comment: The path of g++ is `/usr/bin/g++`. If you are learning C++ then I would neither suggest to use WSL nor VSCode, instead use a real Linux distribution.

Comment: That's where g++ is if I'm trying to get there from within Linux. But what if I'm trying to get there from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Was about looking another solution too

---

`1. The enhanced syntax colorization doesn't work from the remote mode.`

If your syntax lint took a long time, it's because you are workin not directly from your WSL. Still able to read tho, it's just need a time longer.

Assuming you had 2 disk drives `C:/` & `D:/`

Your WSL directory mostly at `\\wsl$` but the installation is under your Windows users `C:\Users`.

You also able to do command `code .` directly inside you WSL terminal. This is what I meant directly inside WSL.

If it's not a part of standard library or your system doesn't read the library directory, intelisense also couldn't able to read it.

*fig1*

[image: std lib & non std lib]

`2. I need to turn my files in for a class and I can't access the Linux files from Windows 10 explorer.`

I tried this before by force include WSL std lib to **System Environment Variables**

Andddd sometimes it's behave improperly, because the ***machine*** read 2 systems.

Used [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/) or [CMake](https://cmake.org/) instead.

*fig2*

[image: using cmake]

---

once it done, everything will work properly
[image: correct behaviour]

---

An alternate compiler for Windows 10 users beside Visual Studio:

- [TDM-GCC](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/)
- [Cygwin](https://sourceware.org/cygwin/)